# Adapting to Python/R as a SAS expert

Tags: python, programming, sql, educational, r

I'm learning Python and R, because so many companies demand those skill sets now. This is me shamelessly looking for training wheels because my older habits are taking time to unlearn.

I am an experienced SAS and SAS EG user with nearly a decade of experience using the associated SQL commands and interfaces.

I'm seeking someone who has made a similar leap that can share their experience on which tools or tricks will aid in the transition.

Answer (score 0):

In case there are no SAS / SAS EG experts who also know Python / R, I'll give some thoughts. I know nothing about SAS, but do know about Python.

Try:

- https://docs.python-guide.org/intro/learning/
- Look into numpy and pandas and plotly

Play with string slicing and List objects, dictionary objects. Try a simple project like parsing CSV data.

For SQL, SQL Alchemy is popular or I recommend [PyMySQl](https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL) because it's a pure Python connector to MySQL database and getting ODBC connectors to work can be a real pain.

https://www.acarrick.com/projects/the-right-tools-for-the-job/

and for my experiences in using Python to create a database: https://www.acarrick.com/projects/category/course-chooser/